# Terraform flappy state

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I have created a Terraform project in order to create s3-buckets, cross region replication, versioning and a livecycle rule to delete old versions.

The problem is, that whenever I run terraform, it want's to delete the cross region replication and livecycle rule, if it exists in AWS, and whenever it does not exist anymore, it wants to readd it. This happens without any code change.
It seems that the state is not accurate.

I already deleted everything from scratch in AWS and started from the beginning, but it didn't help. I always run into the flappy situation.

All the details:

```
$ terraform init && terraform plan -var-file xyz.tfvars

...

Terraform will perform the following actions:

   # module.test_s3_bucket["bnpl-docs"].aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket  will be updated in-place  
    ~   resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
          id                            = "bnpl-docs" 
          tags                          = {}        
         # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)  

       -   replication_configuration {
           -     role   = "arn:aws:iam::....:role/bnpl-docs-s3-bucket-replication"  ->    null    

           -   rules {
               -     id         = "version-replication"  ->    null    
               -     priority   = 0  ->    null    
               -     status     = "Enabled"  ->    null    

               -   destination {
                   -     bucket          = "arn:aws:s3:::bnpl-docs-crr"  ->    null    
                   -     storage_class   = "STANDARD"  ->    null    
                }
            }
        }

         # (1 unchanged block hidden)  
    }

   # module.test_s3_bucket["bnpl-docs"].aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.s3_bucket[0]  will be created  
    +   resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3_bucket" {
       +     bucket   = "bnpl-docs"
       +     id       = (known after apply)

       +   rule {
           +     id       = "version-retention"
           +     status   = "Enabled"

           +   expiration {
               +     days                           = 0 
               +     expired_object_delete_marker   = true
            }

           +   noncurrent_version_expiration {
               +     noncurrent_days   = 30
            }
        }
    }

  Plan:  1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But result is **both** is missing in AWS after running apply.

When I rerun, i get the same output:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

   # module.test_s3_bucket["bnpl-docs"].aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket  will be updated in-place  
    ~   resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
          id                            = "bnpl-docs" 
          tags                          = {}        
         # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)  

       -   replication_configuration {
           -     role   = "arn:aws:iam::......:role/bnpl-docs-s3-bucket-replication"  ->    null  

           -   rules {
               -     id         = "version-replication"  ->    null  
               -     priority   = 0  ->    null   
               -     status     = "Enabled"  ->    null  

               -   destination {
                   -     bucket          = "arn:aws:s3:::bnpl-docs-crr"  ->    null  
                   -     storage_class   = "STANDARD"  ->    null  
                }
            }
        }

         # (1 unchanged block hidden)  
    }

   # module.test_s3_bucket["bnpl-docs"].aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.s3_bucket[0]  will be created  
    +   resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3_bucket" {
       +     bucket   = "bnpl-docs" 
       +     id       = (known after apply)

       +   rule {
           +     id       = "version-retention"
           +     status   = "Enabled"

           +   expiration {
               +     days                           = 0               
               +     expired_object_delete_marker   = true
            }

           +   noncurrent_version_expiration {
               +     noncurrent_days   = 30
            }
        }
    }

  Plan:  1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But result is **both** is created in AWS after running apply.

I have created several modules to realize what I want. The involved code:

```
module "test_s3_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/test-s3-bucket"

  for_each = local.aws_s3_bucket_map

  bucket_name = each.key
  versioning  = each.value.version_config
}

module "test_s3_bucket_repli" {
  source = "./modules/test-s3-bucket"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.repli
  }

  for_each = local.aws_s3_bucket_map_repli

  bucket_name = each.key
  versioning  = each.value.version_config
}

module "test_s3_bucket_repli_config" {
  source = "./modules/test-s3-bucket-replication"

  for_each = local.aws_s3_bucket_map_repli

  src_bucket = {
    name = module.test_s3_bucket[each.value.src_bucket_name].name
    arn  = module.test_s3_bucket[each.value.src_bucket_name].arn
  }
  dest_bucket = {
    name = module.test_s3_bucket_repli[each.key].name
    arn  = module.test_s3_bucket_repli[each.key].arn
  }
}
```

Contents of test_s3_bucket-Module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

##
# Bucket with configuration
##

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id

  acl = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id

  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3_bucket" {
  count = var.versioning == null ? 0 : 1

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
  rule {
    id = var.versioning.rule_id

    expiration {
      expired_object_delete_marker = true
    }

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = var.versioning.expiration_days
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

The contents of the test-s3-bucket-replication module:

```
erraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "bucket_main" {
  bucket = var.src_bucket.name
  role   = aws_iam_role.s3_bucket_main_replication.arn

  rule {
    id     = "version-replication"
    status = "Enabled"

    destination {
      bucket        = var.dest_bucket.arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_bucket_main_replication" {
  name               = "${var.src_bucket.name}-s3-bucket-replication"
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/files/policies/sts-s3-assume.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_bucket_main_replication" {
  name = "${var.src_bucket.name}-s3-bucket-replication"
  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/files/policies/s3-bucket-replication.json", {
    source_bucket_arn      = var.src_bucket.arn,
    destination_bucket_arn = var.dest_bucket.arn,
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "s3_bucket_main_replication" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.s3_bucket_main_replication.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_bucket_main_replication.arn
}
```

You see the two configuration parts which kind of seem to be in conflict are spread over two modules. I'm unsure if this is a problem. I'm kinda new to terraform :)

Comment: It appears the module is erroneously doubly defining the lifecycle rule in a nested block, and in a dedicated resource. This would cause issues when interacting with the AWS API, and is very likely root cause if the module does indeed contain that config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After increasing the Loglevel via TF_LOG="DEBUG", I found out that those two ressources conflicted with the bucket configuration - the aws_s3_bucket-configuration did not include any configuration for lifecycle or replication (as suggested by the documentation), but terraform expected this legacy declaration somehow.
I was using AWS Provider 3.75 and upgraded to 4.X. After this upgrade, everything works as expected.